# Deleting the entire binary search tree at once

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I have been trying to implement the delete BST function but I don't know why it is not working, I think it's logically correct. Can any body please tell me, why I'm getting run time error and how should I correct it.

```
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

class node{
public:
int data;
node *right;
node *left;
node(){
    data=0;
    right=NULL;
    left=NULL;
      }
};

class tree{
node *head;
int maxheight;
     public:
tree(){head=0;maxheight=-1;}
bool deletenode(int key,node* root);
int get_height(){return maxheight;}
void insert(int key);
void pre_display(node* root);
     void delete_tree(node *root);
     node* get_head(){return head;}
         };

void tree::insert(int key){
     node *current=head;
    node *newnode=new node;

    if(newnode==NULL)
    throw(key);

    newnode->data=key;
    int height=0;

if(head==0){
head=newnode;
     }
else
{
    while(1){
    if(current->right==NULL && current->data < newnode->data)
    {
        current->right=newnode;
        height++;
        break;
    }
    else if(current->left==NULL && current->data > newnode->data)
    {
        current->left=newnode;
        height++;
        break;
    }
    else if(current->right!=NULL && current->data < newnode->data)
    {
         current=current->right;
         height++;
   }
    else if(current->left!=NULL && current->data > newnode->data)
    {
               current=current->left;
          height++;
    }
         }
 }
 if(height>maxheight)
 maxheight=height;
 }

 void tree::pre_display(node *root){
 if(root!=NULL)
 {
 cout<<root->data<<" ";
 pre_display(root->left);
 pre_display(root->right);
 }
 }

 void tree::delete_tree(node *root){
  if(root!=NULL)
 {
 delete_tree(root->left);
 delete_tree(root->right);
 delete(root);
 if(root->left!=NULL)
 root->left=NULL;
 if(root->right!=NULL)
 root->right=NULL;
 root=NULL;
 }
 }

int main(){
tree BST;
int arr[9]={17,9,23,5,11,21,27,20,22},i=0;

for(i=0;i<9;i++)
BST.insert(arr[i]);

BST.pre_display(BST.get_head());
cout<<endl;
BST.delete_tree(BST.get_head());
BST.pre_display(BST.get_head());
cout<<endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

All the other functions are working correctly, you just need to check the `delete_tree` function, the other code is provided to give the idea of the structure of my BST.

Comment: Please tick some answers. It's not just for the points (who's here for that, anyway...??), but it's a way for someone with the same problem to go directly to the right solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your delete_tree

```
void tree::delete_tree(node *root){
    if(root!=NULL)
    {
        delete_tree(root->left);
        delete_tree(root->right);
        delete(root);
        if(root->left!=NULL)
            root->left=NULL;
        if(root->right!=NULL)
            root->right=NULL;
        root=NULL;
    }
}
```

you are accessing **root** variable after you have deleted it

Also you call

```
    BST.delete_tree(BST.get_head());
BST.pre_display(BST.get_head());
```

pre_display after deleting tree. **delete_tree** after deleting the tree should also set the BST.head to NULL

Also a critique. BST is of type tree. It already has a head member variable indicating the root node. So delete_tree/pre_display do not need any parameters at all.

Comment: Can i add the implementation of assigning null to the head in the function of delete_tree

Comment: Change delete_tree not to have any args. Have a private iDeleteInternal which does the recursive calls.  So delete_tree calls iDeleteInternal and then set head to NULL before returning

Comment: But if i will do it, as you have said previously to delete after making pointers null, does'nt it mean that i'am losing the position of allocated memory and then iam deleting the null pointer?

Answer (score 2):

You can delete by:
//This is function of cleaning:

```
void cleantree(tree *root){
 if(root->left!=NULL)cleantree(root->left);
 if(root->right!=NULL)cleantree(root->right);
 delete root;}
```

//This is where we call the cleaning function:

```
cleantree(a);
a=NULL;
```

//Where "a" is pointer to root of the tree.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
 delete_tree(root->left);
 delete_tree(root->right);
 delete(root);
 if(root->left!=NULL)
 root->left=NULL;
 if(root->right!=NULL)
 root->right=NULL;
 root=NULL;
```

You're trying to assign NULL to a member of root:

```
root->left=NULL;
```

which was already deleted. There's no need to do that since you're already freeing the memory in `delete_tree(root->left);`

Comment: But if i don't write this statement: root->left=NULL; iam getting error.

Comment: @Zohaib I doubt it. Did you remove everything after delete(root)?

Comment: Iam getting many addresses being print and the run time error.

Answer (score 1):

Recursively delete left and right sub tree and your tree will be deleted as simple as:

```
void delete(node *root){
  // If node is empty, don't bother
  if (root == NULL) { return; }

  // Delete subtrees
  delete(root->left);
  delete(root->right);

  // Delete current node
  free(root);
  root = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I revised it because it actually didn't work, but it helped me get started.

Answer (score 0):

You should not read from root after deleting it.  Move the `delete(root)` line down.

Comment: But if i will do it, what you have said, it does'nt mean that i'am losing the position of allocated memory and then iam deleting the null pointer?

Comment: You should also remove the lines that are setting things to NULL in that function.  There is no need to write to memory which is about to get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: your implementation of the node descriptor missing the correct explicit destructor implementation (the default generated by the compiler will be used by calling the delete operator:calling destructor and releasing the allocated space on the heap)-the one that clear references to the siblings

Answer (score -1):

here is my suggestion using recursivity..

```
 template <class T> void Tree<T>::destroy(Noeud<T> ** r){

            if(*r){
                if(!(*r)->left && !(*r)->right){  //a node having no child
                  delete *r; *r=NULL;
                }else if((*r)->left && (*r)->right){ //a node having two childs
                    destroy(&(*r)->left); //destroy the left tree
                    destroy(&(*r)->right); //destroy the right tree
                    destroy(r); //destroy the node
                }else if((*r)->left){ //a node has only left child
                    destroy(&(*r)->left); //destroy the left tree
                    destroy(r); //destroy the node
                }else if((*r)->right){ //a node has only right child
                    destroy(&(*r)->right); //destroy the right tree
                    destroy(r); //destroy the node
                }
            }
}

//in function main()
int main(){
Tree<int> a(5); // 'a' is a tree of int type with a root value equal 5
a.add(2);a.add(7);a.add(6);a.add(-1);a.add(10); // insert values into the tree 
a.destroy(&a.root);  //destroy the tree
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.